# como posso desabilitar qualquer clique do teclado em JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Olá !! Me chamo Weslley.

Estou escrevendo um jogo em JAVASCRIPT para aprimoramento técnico e quando o personagem "morre" ele trava na tela e o usuário precisa atualizar para começar o game novamente, POREM, mesmo morto o usuário consegue se mexer, preciso de algum código que cancele cliques no teclado e force o usuário a recarregar a página.

Estou pesquisando quando ao disable do keydown, mas não consegui formular em código de um modo que funciona, tipo
keydown = disabled;
??

Comment: Maybe [pt.so]??